# Is that possible to reshape/reorder csv file without using pandas library

Tags: python, csv, tableau-api, export-to-csv, csvreader

I am extracting data from Tableau and generate a CSV file. I need to reshape the CSV file without using pandas library.My 3P policy wont allow to install any other packages. *(Default package I am using is `csv`)*

My generate CSV file :

```
Name,Experience,Measure names,Measure values
Birla,3,State,CA
Birla,3,Audit,Y
Birla,3,WFH,Y
Birla,3,State,MN
Birla,3,Audit,N
Birla,3,WFH,N
Birla,6,State,SC
Birla,6,Audit,Y
Birla,6,WFH,Y
Rosa,5,State,LA
Rosa,5,Audit,N
Rosa,5,WFH,N
Val,8,State,CO
Val,8,Audit,P
Val,8,WFH,N
Brain,12,State,MO
Brain,12,Audit,Y
Brain,12,WFH,N
Brain,12,State,NY
Brain,12,Audit,N
Brain,12,WFH,Y
```

[image]

My expected output should be :

```
Name,Experience,State,Audit,WFH
Birla,3,CA,Y,Y
Birla,3,MN,N,N
Birla,6,SC,Y,Y
Rosa,5,LA,N,N
Val,8,CO,P,N
Brain,12,MO,Y,N
Brain,12,NY,N,Y
```

[image]

Is that possible using Default `csv` package? Request your suggestion on this.

Comment: This is doable with the standard `csv` module. Also, please use text rather than images.

Comment: Is your CSV always sorted by *Name* column? Every *Name* has 3 measurements?

Comment: @wkl-Could you please  tell me steps to do that.I am unable to add that as text..When i tried it show me a picture

Comment: @OlvinRoght-Due to Measurement names and Measurement values,Additional rows were generated,i am tring to avoid that

Comment: @Staycool, once again. Is it guaranteed that all data related to `Birla` will be grouped one by one? Are there only *State*, *Audit* and *WFH* measurements?

Comment: No we should not group by birla...If We have same name for another scenario,then we  groupby my sceario wont possible right..Name,Experience is duplicated since we have (state,Audit & WFH) came as rows..For you let me add me another scenario with name "birla"

Comment: @Staycool, try [this](https://tio.run/##bVE9b4MwEN35FScmO0JZulRI2dqxGbJ0qRS55AiWwLYOExpV/e30bD5T1QOYe@/dvXe4u6@seXp2NAwl2QaK9ga6cZY8vOjCn1BdkLJ4fyftkZJICzdvbd3O5CvZzn3eR9Q6JOUtzSCzmyv6oE567atAMIJSbVzn9zwylaC4lTmXGXwkMJ2JZTs/0zJIe34Y7Gtt8JCOOiacyzzKKPqFw8a8CG1lRPuYgNGjNRgrJZsUJgOUWXQZTMxZBE3hV/siPaoGg43XL86o0RSYSpkvlsn23P57@Q5n1OTAYx7rmx454B90t7twBNEoJ7bz31C1HSEY7tkGI3PhpuqOK3MOKZduP8tNl2Csn9aQP4xbVrP@aRH3moVM8h/uPr6qcccrYQuyUgT1MPwC).

Comment: @Staycool, or [this](https://tio.run/##bVA7b4MwEN75FRaTHVmoj6VCypauWTu0VUTJESwFn@UcJVHV307PNtCkqgewv5e@O3ehFu3jk/PjaDqHnkR9@swaj50wBJ4QjycxMQePvfu4JBYd@IrQzySruwMQe7JsMNQGgZU@N9b1VHBorkTFUXbXaPGWielMKuxplmmRD/yxMByNhXWefCzYNWW0eaj24MU6NC3SQ4ZYFVkLZ5IJTcDgwyAs36KFiDTcWlotQOlYO7Sah5us@moeeafFvVLl0tnjwHFfyzucfFt1kJeCY2/x5zMvyoCtAwt/2NVqb2qS5vWhfI@1TKgSO6lF@L3cTCMs0jRReZO0TBmWsuHQlwjIuDcdKqt/9EX8tWmHv4Jrkp0yuMfxBw) using simple `reader()`.

Comment: @OlvinRoght..Let me check.But i can see "Name","Experience" column name was hard code in Program.But it will not gauranteed we had only 2 columns and the name was same....So it will 12-14 columns names including "measure names","measure values".COlumn name "measure names" and "measure values"  -column name will be same for all reports.

Comment: Is that possibble to save as same csv file...?

Comment: @Staycool, yes, it's possible, you need to not write modified columns to separate file but save it into a list and reopen file for writing after and write modified data back

Comment: @OlvinRoght Thanks a lot it gives the expected result.Let me ad another case...Please take a look at that...in that scenario we cant group by 'name' or ' experience'